# Theorem numbering after redefining sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems

**I counter this problem when I try to establish a simple
template for my numerical report.**

The demo codes are below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Thm}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{adssd}
    \begin{theorem}
        $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$.
    \end{theorem}
\section{adssd}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

I just want special section title, i.e. the Roman number
and normal theorem number(such as Thm 1.1). **I want to ask how to get
these two styles in the same time.**

Comment: `\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}` but that's going to confuse any reader.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle WOW! I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}` but that's going to confuse any reader.